# command cant working on discord bot at new version

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   deneme=["Besim Tibuk Online!","Bu Kitap benim","Satacağız!","Özelleştireceğiz!"]
   await client.get_channel(#########).send(random.choice(deneme))

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong")
```

"client.command()" side cant working.When ı write "ping" I cant get response

Comment: I actually writing "!ping"

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your on_message, you arent processing commands. To process commands, do `await client.process_commands(message)`. Here is the reworked code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
    await client.process_commands(message)
```